# How to use match against and Replace at a time

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have data in my column like "Nesbo, jo". Its already index with full text and working properly with match against. But my problem is, when is search like "jonesbo" its not getting results. for this i found replace comma and space. but when i tried match against replace is not working properly

### Below is my Query:

```
SELECT *,REPLACE(columnname,', ','') FROM `tablename` 
WHERE MATCH(REPLACE(columnname,', ','')) AGAINST("jonesbo")
```

Comment: Please always add the error message you get. "is not working properly" can mean several things. (e.g. getting wrong result). Here it is clear you get an error message, as you just cannot do this. A fulltext index is a simple list of all words of specific columns. You cannot apply a function to it, since it would be a different list. You can however add a column to your table using your function (although it would make it `nosbojo`, not `jonesbo`) and add it to the fulltext index . Or not use a fulltext index, but e.g. `like`. Or use `against ("jo nesbo")` by using a function on your input.

Comment: Hi Solarflare... as a programmer i can do it...with space...but user may not be type with space...so, i need results with that search

Comment: I gave you 3 options to do it. And yes, I meant that as a programmer, you could use a function on user input. You could e.g. generate all combinations by adding a space at every possible place (the order of words in a ft search doesn't matter). "Nesbo, Jo" and "Jonesbo" are two complete different things. If you want to allow your user to enter garbage and still find what they mean, you unfortunately have to do more than just use a basic fulltext search (which is fast but expects clean data) and hope it works. You could add e.g. alternative versions of your data, maybe include `Harri Whole`.

Comment: Is there any other options without modifying table Solarflare?

Comment: Yes, as i said twice, you could use a function on user input (e.g generate all combinations by adding a space at every possible place). Also, as I already said too, you could not use a fulltext search, but e.g. `like`. Then you can use `replace`, e.g. `WHERE REPLACE(columnname,', ','')) like '%jonesbo%'` (but keep in mind that your `replace` doesn't actually generate `jonesbo`, but `nesbojo`, so fix it first). Although if you would split first and surnames in your data into two columns, it becomes A LOT easier (as usual, cleaner data = easier access to data). Or just dont allow garbage input.